# Why can't I multiply an object?

Tags: java, android, class, object

I'm working with Android (Java), and what I want is to take a class, and make 3 instances out of it, but with some variables set to random.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    Player ourView; 

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ourView = new Player(this);
        setContentView(ourView);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ourView.pause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ourView.resume();
    }
}
```

The other class...

```
public class Player extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    Thread ourThread = null;
    boolean isRunning = true;

    public Player(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        isRunning = false;
        while(true){
        try{
            ourThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    ourThread = null;
}

    public void resume() {
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(isRunning) {
            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

                canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawRGB(30, 30, 200);

                Enemy[] enemy = new Enemy[3];
                for(int i = 0; i<enemy.length; i++){
                    enemy[i] = new Enemy();
                    enemy[i].draw();
                }

            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }           
    }
}
```

And the "Enemy" class:

```
public class Enemy{

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    float x = (float) (Math.random()*200);
    float y = (float) (Math.random()*200);

    public void draw(){
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);

    }
}
```

I can see that there are 3 bitmaps created, which is cool. But they don't stay still, it's like if the for loop never stops even though the condition is no longer satisfied.

I've asked the question before but I couldn't find any answer. Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: "Why can't I multiply an object". What do you mean by that?

Comment: Which 'for' loop is never satisfied?

Comment: I'm thinking they mean the 'while' loop?

Comment: When you say "the condition is no longer satisfied" do you mean `isRunning`?  It looks like that is set to false only when the app is paused.  Is that the intended behavior?  Are you sure `onPause()` is getting called?  You might want to try using `Log.d` to make sure it's getting called.  Also try adding `volatile` to the declaration of `isRunning`.

Comment: I mean the "for" loop. Because when the int "i" gets to the value of 3, the loop should stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new array of 3 enemies every cycle of the while loop, once the while loop completes execution, the enemy array will leave the scope and be destroyed and a new array will be created. If you want to keep these enemies you will need to store them outside of the scope of the loop.

** EDIT ** - Try this

```
public class Player extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
Thread ourThread = null;
boolean isRunning = true;
Enemy[] enemy;

public Player(Context context) {
    super(context);
    ourHolder = getHolder();
    ourThread = new Thread(this);
    ourThread.start();
    enemy = new Enemy[3];
    for(int i = 0; i<enemy.length; i++){
        enemy[i] = new Enemy();
    }
}

public void pause() {
    isRunning = false;
    while(true){
    try{
        ourThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    break;
}
ourThread = null;
}

public void resume() {
    isRunning = true;
}

public void run() {
    while(isRunning) {
        if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

            canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawRGB(30, 30, 200);


            for(int i = 0; i<enemy.length; i++){
                enemy[i].draw();
            }

        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }           
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I do that?

Comment: Create the enemies when you create the player or in a new function and store them as members of the class like you do with canvas or float x. Then in your run() function all you do is draw the enemies that are already created.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude but if you can't figure that out, a game might be a bit too ambitious of a project for your current skill level.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying to learn. I wrote the for loop inside a void function, but when I call it inside the Run method, it's exactly the same: it gets called over and over again.

Comment: you don't call it inside the run method, it will happen exactly as you said. Try calling it in the Player's Constructor where you call getHolder();

Comment: The thing is, if I don't call it inside the Run method, it doesn't have a bitmap to draw.

Comment: It worked! Thanks very much for taking the time and I'm sorry if I gave you a headache. I'm quite new with java and I was wondering, how much time does it take to really learn the language?

Comment: No problem, make sure you accept the answer to show your appreciation. As for learning Java, I went to a 4 year school to get a Bachelors, we mostly used Java and I was still pretty inexperienced. You never really stop learning when it comes to programming.

Answer (score 1):

exactly as you said, it is like if the for loop never stops. 
because that for loop is in while(isrunning) loop that never stops and triggers your for loop over and over.

you need to reorganize your code.

Comment: I'm working on a game, so if I set the loop outside the while loop it won't work. Right? Because it's supposed to be running constantly.

Comment: enemy behaviour is supposed to be there and run constantly. that means AI. collision check, death-checks.

but enemy creation should be elswhere

Comment: I wrote the enemy creation inside a void function, but when I call it inside the Run method it's exactly the same as before: it's get called over and over again.

Comment: That is because you call in on wrong place. 
You obviously dont understand your own code. Scope of you enemy classes is ridiculously useless.
 
your fix is to move  Enemy[] enemy = new Enemy[3]; as Player class variable and its forloop initiation to player class constructor. but advice you need is to start with something simpler. At very least go for game that is not realtime